# Trying to disable a working site; a2dissite returns 'ERROR: Site [such] does not exist!'

Tags: apache2

I am new to website setups, never used a web server before this recent little while.  I am stumped by this basic step, though; I cannot stop a working site with the `a2dissite` command:

```
$ sudo a2dissite [such]
ERROR: Site [such] does not exist!
```

There is no typo possible as I get the same results by using wildcards.  Actually, using the * wildcard with chosen letters returns a full sentence: `ERROR: Site [the_full_name_such] does not exist!`

Could my `sites-*` folders be somehow corrupted, or a `conf` file?

What are good troubledshooting steps?

Comment: How do you named the conf-file?

Answer (score 2):

The following is the report of significant progresses made regarding my problem.

First troubleshooting step taken was: take time to read the code of the `a2dissite` script found in `/usr/sbin`.  Realize that I usually troubleshoot well by modifying code.

Second troubleshooting step: make a copy with a diffrent name, and execute for testing purposes.  Repeat the problem: FAIL.  Call with perl: FAIL.  Give up on echoing info from the script.

Third troubleshooting step: call `man a2dissite` and docuread.  The interesting bit says:

```
   FILES

   /etc/apache2/sites-available
          Directory with files giving information on available sites.

   /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
          Directory with links to the files in sites-available for enabled
          sites.
```

I then see that I have a true file in `sites-enabled` and no 'corresponding' file in `sites-available`.  The lack of file in `sites-available` was the reason for the error message.

The following apparently fixed my problematic symptoms:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled $ sudo mv [such_site.conf] ../sites-available/[such_site.conf]
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled $ sudo ln ../sites-available/[such_site.conf] [such_site.conf]
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled $ sudo a2dissite [such_site]
ERROR: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[such_site.conf] is not a symbolic link, not deleting
Site [such_site] disabled.
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled $ sudo rm [such_site.conf]
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled $ sudo a2dissite [such_site]
Site [such_site] already disabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Small correction in the above answer.

While you create links please create symbolic link instead of hard links.

Soft link to a file (-s).

```
sudo ln -s ../sites-available/[such_site.conf] [such_site.conf]
```